# Пайтон.Замена символов

Tags: python, python-3.x

ПОМОГИТЕ:НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ ЗАДАЧУ!!

Дано натуральное число n, символы s1, ..., sn. Превратить последовательность s1, ...,
sn: если нет символа * , то оставить ее без изменения, иначе заменить каждый символ,
встречается после первого вхождения символа * , в знак «-».
Пример:
Вводим:456456
Вывод:456456

Вводим:456*456
Вывод:456---

```
n = input("Введите последовательность: ")
sum = 0
for  i in n:
    sum +=1
    if (i =='*'):
        n.replace('*', '-', 1)
        print(n)
```

Comment: Думаешь, если в первый раз вопрос закрыли, то во второй раз прокатит?

Comment: та я хз как это зделать

Comment: @НикитаЧекалин, попробуйте сами поделать, а потом если что-то не выходит, то приложить вашу наработку с просьбой помочь. А так, в этой задаче используйте `input` для ввода в программу, цикл `for` для перебора символов строки, введенной через input(), и проверки через `if`, чтобы определить символ `'*'` и после него игнорировать символы строки и добавлять `'-'`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо,щас уже сижу пробую

Comment: @gil9red вот впринципе,но я только учусьn = input("Введите последовательность: ")
sum = 0
for  i in n:
    sum +=1
    if (i =='*'):
        n.replace('*', '-', 1)
        print(n)

Comment: @НикитаЧекалин в каком месте это работает? ты вообще тестил?

Comment: @gil9red почему-то нечего не выводится,в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение -- через создание новой строку на основе текущей:

- Цикл, что перебирает символы из строки
- Проверка встречи с `'*'`
- Код добавления символа в зависимости от флага. Состояние флага указывает что добавляется в новую строку: текущий символ строки или `'-'`

Пример:

```
# text = '456*456'
text = input("Введите последовательность: ")

flag = False
new_text = ''
for c in text:
    if c == '*':
        flag = True
        continue

    if flag:
        new_text += '-'
    else:
        new_text += c

print(new_text)
```

---

**PS.**

Условие можно в одну строку сделать:

```
new_text += '-' if flag else c
```

Comment: почему-то нечего не вводится ,в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверьте, что правильно написали. Вот пример в интерактивную консоль: `>>> text = input("Введите последовательность: ")`
`Введите последовательность: ddfdf`
`>>> text`
`'ddfdf'`. Если через IDE запускаете, то вводите в консоль IDE, если та консоль не работает, запускайте через консоль ОС, например через cmd